# DateTime keeps throwing an exception for "string not recognized as valid DateTime"

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

Here's the string:

```
string date = "Fri Feb 17 15:50:42 +00:00 2012";
```

I'm just trying to parse it using:

```
DateTime.Parse(date, new Culture("en-us"));
DateTime.Parse(date);
```

No matter what I do it keeps coming back as invalid string.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have to tell the Parse command HOW TO PARSE the string.  It is trying to use the default, using the "en-us" culture, your string will not match the default format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd look into specifying the format you want using `ParseExact`:

If you want a DateTime use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131038.aspx):

```
DateTime.ParseExact("Fri Feb 17 15:50:42 +00:00 2012",
                    "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy",
                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                    DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal)
```

Or since you're handling arbitrary offsets, [`DateTimeOffset`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343428.aspx) is probably the better choice:

```
DateTimeOffset.ParseExact("Fri Feb 17 15:50:42 +00:00 2012",
                          "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy",
                          CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```